# Getting unexpected result when changing from innerHTML to form, input type text Field

Tags: javascript, html

When I tested my code using innerHTML gave var num1=57; got correct result 73.375, now when change code to use a form with input type text box when entering number 57 it changes expected result to 629.625.. any help with this would be appreciated

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
```

```
<head>
      <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8"/>
      <link rel="style" href="css/main.css"  type"text/css"/>
      <title> Get final width </title>

      <script type= "text/javascript">

            function sum()
            {

            var num1;
            num1= document.getvalue.width.value;


            var acc1 = (num1 + 0.625)/(6.25-0.5); 
            var acc2 = Math.ceil((acc1 * 10) / 10) * 6.25 + (4.125 + 0.5);

            document.getElementById('finalwidth').value = (acc2).toFixed(3);
            document.getElementById("finalwidth").readOnly=true;
            }
      </script>       
</head>

<body>
            <div>
            <h3> when input is 57  final width result should be : 73.375</h3>
            <h3> when input is 100  final width result should be : 117.125</h3>
            </div>

            <form name= "getvalue">

                    <label for="width"> Width: </label>
                    <input type="text" name="width" maxlength="5" size="10" value=""/>

                    <input type="button" name="button" Value="calculate" onclick="sum()"/>

                    <label for="finalwidth"> Final width: </label>
                    <input type="text" id="finalwidth" name="finalwidth" maxlength="4" size="10" value=""/>

            </form> 
</body>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Try this out:- http://jsfiddle.net/adiioo7/6q8u5/1/

**JS:-**

```
function sum() {

    var num1;
    num1 = parseInt(document.getvalue.width.value);


    var acc1 = (num1 + 0.625) / (6.25 - 0.5);
    var acc2 = Math.ceil((acc1 * 10) / 10) * 6.25 + (4.125 + 0.5);

    document.getElementById('finalwidth').value = (acc2).toFixed(3);
    document.getElementById("finalwidth").readOnly = true;
}
```

Comment: @bigdog Does this answer your question?

Comment: Yes it does I stripped it down glad I did, I have other inputs with similar formulas I had parseInt at the end of code when I was multiplying etc. thank you very much

Answer (score 0):

When you do:

```
num1 = document.getvalue.width.value;
```

the value of *num1* is a string (since form control values are always strings). So when you do:

```
num1 + 0.625
```

the values are concatenated as strings, not added as numbers. So if the value of *num1* is say `57`, then the result of the above expression will be the string `570.625`. Because other arithmetic operations are conducted, the final result of:

```
(num1 + 0.625)/(6.25 - 0.5)
```

will be a number.

The simple fix is to convert *num1* to a number using the unary `+` operator:

```
var num1 = +document.getvalue.width.value;
```

or

```
var acc1 = (+num1 + 0.625)/(6.25 - 0.5)
```

You can also be more explicit and use Number as a function:

```
var num1 = Number(document.getvalue.width.value);
```